# why can't get file size in objective c? always return 0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i am a new to objective c, i tried many hours to find out how to get file size but i failed, please help me, thx a lot.

first i use code like this:

```
NSString *yourPath = @"http://www.xxx.com.au/magazine/nm.pdf";
NSFileManager *man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error: nil];
unsigned long long result = [[attrs objectForKey: NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue];
NSLog(@"%llu", result);
```

output is 0

then i try this:

```
NSString *yourPath = @"http://www.xxx.com.au/magazine/nm.pdf";
unsigned long long result = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error:nil] fileSize];
NSLog(@"%llu", result);
```

also get 0. Same result after i change path to local file.

Comment: You see those error arguments? Use them and log them.

Comment: Check the error values. They might be returning why things aren't working correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is not a path, it's an URL with http protocol.

`NSFileManager` only works for filesystem files (expects paths, not urls). Also use of `NSFileManager` is no more the recommended way to get the size of a file in Cocoa.

The recommended way now is to use `NSURL`. But it must be a 'file url' (create it with `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath]`). If it is a 'file url' you can use `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` or `resourceValuesForKeys:error:` to get information like the file size.

In your case, however, you do not have a path, but an http URL. An http URL refers to a resource, not to a file (a resource may or may not be a file). If it's a file there's no way to know its size without at least starting to download it. Depending on how the server responds it may or may not be possible to know the size at the beginning of the download. In the worst case you only know the size after downloading the file completely.

Comment: You don't have to start the download, a normal file server should send the size in the response to http HEAD.

Comment: Head is like starting a download and terminating it before getting the data. It may or may not give you the length of the file. Many servers will just give you a Transfer-Encoding instead of a Content-Length and you'll then have to download the file to know the actual size.

Comment: Thx Analog, i will try nsurl coz i have download function.